# Winter '18 - Is it now possible in LEX to add mass action buttons to invoke Lightning components?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, winter18

With Winter '18 SF has added checkboxes to object lists in LEX, with some built in mass actions.  Is it now possible to add a mass action to invoke a custom Lightning Component from the same list?

I've looked through the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/salesforce_release_notes.htm), but couldn't find if this is yet possible.

Maybe this feature was added previously?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, no lightning yet, onClick JS > Visualforce is supported

[image: Here is Search Layouts > Create a List View Button]

To add to woes List, a quick look at the List View Lightning component doesn't seem to support multiple record select, even though it has in-line edit.
First pic is the standard list view, second pic is the lightning component list view

[image: Here is an Oppty Standard List View, it has multi record select]

[image: and here is the same view]

Comment: Two years out, has this changed?